# Is it possible to update 3 sql rows in 1 sql update statement

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table like this.

```
id          Order
======== =========
1                4
2                3
3                5
4                1
5                2
```

Is it possible to update multiple rows in 1 sql statement?
i.e. I want to update id = 3, order = 1 and id = 5, order = 4 and id = 1, order = 1

I know how to do that in 3 update statements. But I would like to know if I can update 3 rows in 1 sql update statement.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with a single `UPDATE` statement, but I wouldn't bother.

It makes more sense to use three separate updates in this situation. Trying to do it with one statement makes your code less readable and more error-prone.

But if you really want the single statement, here you go:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET order = CASE id
                WHEN 3 THEN 1
                WHEN 5 THEN 4
                WHEN 1 THEN 1
            END
WHERE id IN (3, 5, 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to update three rows in one statement?

If the rows must all be in sync with one another, you can do:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE... ;
UPDATE... ;
UPDATE... ;
COMMIT
```

That way, all work between the begin and commit, is either all completed or none of it is done. This is a key feature of SQL-based relational databases. Even [SQLITE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) has this capability.

Comment: Right. Unless you go deeper down the rabbit hole and discover that those two things are not necessarily identical. See transaction isolation levels.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
update Orders
set 
  Order = (
    case 
      when id = 3 then 1
      when id = 5 then 4
      when id = 1 then 1
    end
where id in (3, 5, 1)
```

Depends on your database though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE if your DBMS supports it.